# Can't able send email via java mail API?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I want to send mail from my java(JSP) project that is basically a Web based project to user.
But i'm getting an error.give me solution of this.

I tried a lot of solution that is provided on net but nothing will work out.
I changed port no 465 to 587 but my error is still there.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;  

public class MailUtil {    
    private String from1 = "fromemail@gmail.com";  
    private String  password= "*****";  
    private String FROM_NAME = "abc";  

    public boolean sendMail(String[] recipients, String[] bccRecipients, String subject, String message) {  
        try {  
            Properties props = new Properties(); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
           // props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.debug", "false");  
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");  

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from1, password);
                }
            });  
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  

            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(from, name);  
            msg.setFrom(from);  

            InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];  
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {  
                toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);  


            InternetAddress[] bccAddresses = new InternetAddress[bccRecipients.length];  
            for (int j = 0; j < bccRecipients.length; j++) {  
                bccAddresses[j] = new InternetAddress(bccRecipients[j]);  
            }  
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);  

            msg.setSubject(subject);  
            msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");  
            Transport.send(msg);  
            return true;  
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

SEVERE: null

javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. d129sm8507654pfa.142 - gsmtp

```
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
```

Comment: Lets check this out > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719679/java-mail-has-connection-errors/40719864#40719864

Comment: If the problem still is continuing, as far as I know, you should turn on 'Allow less secure apps for your Gmail account'

Answer (score 0):

First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

If that doesn't fix the problem, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).